# Move Office 365 data to new datacenter

Tags: office365, exchange

I'm from UAE, we're running Office 365 and while creating the tenant I selected the Europe region because at that time the United Arab Emirates data location was not available, now Microsft has launched their data center in UAE. Due to compliance issues, we want to move the Office 365 data to my country, how can it be possible?

According to the articles below, this option was provided at the time of UAE country launching but is now unavailable.

https://office365atwork.com/admin/migrate-core-data-to-new-datacenter-geos/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/request-your-data-move?view=o365-worldwide

Comment: Have you contacted Microsoft to determine if it’s even possible? I would imagine the data privacy laws are significantly different in UAE compared to Europe.

Comment: Basically we didn't procure the Microsoft support that's why I'm seeking expert opinion here.

Comment: I am not entirely sure if we CAN answer the question, since you are asking about the data stored within your Enterprise Office 365 account. It seems logically that unless you get an exception from Microsoft to export the data, then you are likely out of luck, due to Microsoft preventing the export request.

Answer (score 0):

It's suggested that you could refer to these article and check if your situation meets the criteria.

- [How to request your data move](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/request-your-data-move?view=o365-worldwide)
- [Moving core data to new Microsoft 365 datacenter geos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/moving-data-to-new-datacenter-geos?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.